# SwitchPreference shows up in a smaller font size than other preference types on Preferences screen

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, sharedpreferences

Why is this happening and how to make it appear in the same font size as other preferences?

Here's how it looks in Android Studio's design view as well as on the device.

[image]

The corresponding code is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

...
...

    <EditTextPreference
        android:key="@string/businessAddr1"
        android:maxLength="32"
        android:selectAllOnFocus="false"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:title="Address Line 1"
        android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"/>

    <EditTextPreference
        android:key="@string/businessAddr2"
        android:maxLength="32"
        android:selectAllOnFocus="false"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:title="Address Line 2"
        android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"/>

    <SwitchPreference
        android:defaultValue="false"
        android:key="@string/debugString"
        android:title="Debug" />
    <CheckBoxPreference
        android:defaultValue="false"
        android:key="check_box_preference_1"
        android:title="Check box preference" />
    <SwitchPreference
        android:defaultValue="false"
        android:key="switch_preference_1"
        android:title="Switch preference" />

</PreferenceScreen>
```